# Error when playing audio with createAudioPlayer

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, trigger.io

I want to [play audio in my app](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/media.html).

When running the following:

```
forge.file.getLocal("audio/it's time for your.mp3", function(file) {
  debug(null,file);
  forge.media.createAudioPlayer(file.uri, function(player) {
    debug(player);
    player.play();
  }, function(err) {
    error(err);
  });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
[FORGE] '{"message":"Failed to load audio file","type":"EXPECTED_FAILURE","subtype":null}
```

The same goes with `.m4a` (what I actually would like to play), `.aiff`, and `.ac3`.

I know it's finding the file:

```
{"uri":"/var/mobile/Applications/AC963D11-88EC-4559-9C2E-68F666AC44D5/Library/Application Support/Forge/assets-7CF461FB-5BE1-445E-A51E-CA69CFCFF122/src/audio/it\'s time for your.ac3"}
```

What's the error here? I'm using an iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you just need to use `file` instead of `file.uri` as the parameter.